# Creating a new column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (called msg_df) that has a column called "messages". This column has, for each row, a list of dictionaries as values 
(example:

```
msg_df['messages'][0]
output: 
[{'id': 1, 'date': '2018-12-04T16:26:13Z', 'type': 'b'},
{'id': 2, 'date': '2018-12-11T15:28:49Z', 'type': 'i'},
{'id': 3, 'date': '2018-12-04T16:26:13Z', 'type': 'c'}] )
```

What I need to do is to create a new column, let's call it "filtered_messages", which only contains the dictionaries that have 'type': 'b' and 'type': 'i'.

The problem is, when I apply a list comp to a single value, it works, for example:

```
test = msg_df['messages'][0]
keys_list = ['b','i']
filtered = [d for d in test if d['type'] in keys_list]
filtered
```

output:
[{'id': 1, 'date': '2018-12-04T16:26:13Z', 'type': 'b'},
{'id': 2, 'date': '2018-12-11T15:28:49Z', 'type': 'i'}]

the output is the filtered list, however, I am not being able to:
1. apply the same concept to the whole column, row by row
2. obtain a new column with the values being the filtered list

New to Python, really need some help over here.

PS: Working on Jupyter, have pandas, numpy, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As a general remark, this looks like a weird pandas structure. The underlying containers from pandas are numpy arrays, which means that pandas is very good at numeric processing, and *can* store other type elements. And storing containers is pandas cell is not better...

That being said, you can use `apply` to apply a Python function to every element of a pandas Series, said differently to a DataFrame column:

```
keys_list = ['b','i']
msg_df['filtered_messages'] = msg_df['messages'].apply(lambda x:
                                [d for d in test if d['type'] in keys_list])
```

Comment: Hey Serge, thanks for answering!

The thing is I don't want to apply it to "test", I want to apply it for the whole msg_df, creating a new column...

Know how can I do?

Comment: tried doing

> keys_list = ['bid','interview_events']
> msg_df['filtered_messages'] = msg_df['messages'].apply(lambda x:
                                [d for d in msg_df if d['type'] in keys_list])
> msg_df.head()

recieved this error: string indices must be integers

Comment: You should build an extract of your dataframe exhibiting the error and share it here. If I have enough data to reproduce, I will probably be able to fix my code. But if I have not, then I cannot...

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to do that, I'm gonna try and hit you up...

Comment: @FaridLondono `msg_df.iloc[:10]` will extract the 10 first rows...

Comment: I was able to solve the problem: since each value was an array of dictionaries, i had to create an "empty array" and then apply a for loop and append()

thanks for your help Serge!!!